# Class property not visible inside ajax callback function?

Tags: ajax, oop

I have a class that has ajax callbacks inside it, as well as actions set in the `__construct()` of that class. I am also passing the property to the class when instantiating it. It looks kinda like this

```
<?php

class My_Class{

    private $passed_string;

    public function __construct( $passed_string ) {
        $this->$passed_string = $passed_string;

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_callback', array( $this, 'my_callback' ) );
    }

    public function my_callback() {

        error_log( print_r( $this->$passed_string, true ) );
        wp_die();
    }

}

$init = new My_Class( 'Passed string!' );
```

Now this should show in my error logs when I call this function with ajax. But it's empty.

The callback works (tested).

The thing is that when doing this in a similar class that has a method inside, that is not hooked to `wp_ajax` hook it works, and I see the passed string just fine.

How come?

Answer (score -1):

Have you used AJAX before? Do you know what the acronym stands for? Hint: The `J` stands for `javascript`. Indeed, AJAX is usually invoked using javascript/jQuery. I believe that's why you're not receiving a response: you aren't invoking an AJAX protocol or going through Wordpress's admin-ajax.php.

And, why would you put a callback function in a constructor in the first place?

Comment: No, never ever used ajax before.... :roll:
If you have a better suggestion for where to put the hook for ajax callback then by all means do tell...

Comment: May I suggest you start by reading the Wordpress Codex (https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX) and then google "using ajax in wordpress." If the use cases presented don't match what you are trying to do, then you don't need AJAX!